# Custom trim my post title item combine two if

Tags: php, wordpress, trim, facetwp

based on this [example](https://facetwp.com/documentation/developers/output/facetwp_builder_item_value/)

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_builder_item_value', function( $value, $item ) {
    if ( 'post_excerpt' == $item['source'] ) {
        $value = substr( $value, 0, 120 );
    }
    return $value;
}, 10, 2 );
```

I would like to **trim post_title** to a maximum **limit of 120** with the **(...)** at the end.

This objective was not achieved with my modification and I failed several times with several combinations

```
   // my actual attemp to trim post_title item

   add_filter( 'facetwp_builder_item_value', function( $value, $item ) {
    if ( 'post_title' == $item['source'] ) {
          $raw_value = $item['source'];
      if ( 120 < strlen( $raw_value ) ) {
            $value['source'] = substr( $raw_value, 0, 120 ) . "...";
        }
    }
    return $value;
}, 10, 2 );
```

following **the logic of the things** based on this exemple [mentioned here](https://gist.facetwp.com/?_keywords=trim)

```
// Add the following to your theme's functions.php
add_filter( 'facetwp_index_row', function( $params, $class ) {
    if ( 'aufsichtsbehoerden' == $params['facet_name'] ) {
        $raw_value = $params['facet_value'];
        if ( 50 < strlen( $raw_value ) ) {
            $params['facet_value'] = substr( $raw_value, 0, 50 ); // cut off some of the value
        }
    }
    return $params;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Experts in PHP and use filters are requested to join me to tell me what I missed as a modification ..

Comment: Is it a WordPress function?

Comment: yes for wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest your if statements, and add some way of tracking the bug.

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_builder_item_value', function( $value, $item ) {
    if ( 'post_title' == $item['source']) {
        $maxLength = 120;
        echo "POST TITLE == ITEM SOURCE";
        if (strlen($value) > $maxLength) {
            echo "POST TITLE EXCEEDED MAX LENGTH";
            $value = substr( $value, 0, $maxLength) . '…';
        }
    }
return $value;
}, 10, 2 );
```

I have added two echo functions to allow you to understand where and when the conditions are met.

Comment: thank you for your answer I'm trying to investigate what goes wrong I have no errors in the console, what is strange is the title in my loop card if I put 120 limit it bug the page becomes buggy display and even titles less than 120 are also reduced! it's really strange something is wrong somewhere ... i took my code following [the documentation here](https://facetwp.com/documentation/developers/output/facetwp_builder_item_value/)

Comment: If that is the case then, if (strlen($value) > 120) is not producing the desired output. Ca you post a dump of $value with var_dump($value) before and after the substr transformation? I have also edited my answer as I believe that your title length is better off saved into a variable.

Comment: thank you bios for all the messages and the help, it seems to work no errors but the page and the (loop my cards) reacts very very badly chaotic bug desing and everything is mixed if not gone. I think that's not the way to do it apparently

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` is doing nothing in the first code. Notice that there are nothing between its brackets `{ }`.

Your second code is combining both conditions correctly. If it doesn't work, `'post_title'` is probably not equal to `$item['source']`.

Comment: thank you for your answer I'm trying to investigate what goes wrong I have no errors in the console, what is strange is the title in my loop card if I put 120 limit it bug the page becomes buggy display and even titles less than 120 are also reduced! it's really strange something is wrong somewhere ... i took my code following [the documentation here](https://facetwp.com/documentation/developers/output/facetwp_builder_item_value/)